# Embedding encryption in the android cm9 platform

Tags: android, makefile, openssl, libraries, platform

The thing that I am trying to do is to use the android's openssl libraries so I would like to add the library at some other embedded applications and just keep the data encrypted. I tried this things on the cyanogen 7.1 platform by just adding:

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /external/openssl/include

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libssl libcrypto

in the Android.mk file of the current project and I was able to use all functions with a simple #include in the particular .c file.

Alas, all this does not work just as straightforward on cyanogen 9 and I am looking for some help. Could you please tell me if there is something changed in the build system or something else that I need to do?

For example I have errors of this kind:

undefined reference to `EVP_get_cipherbyname'
undefined reference to`OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'.

I would just like to repeat that I port all the code and all the things that I did on cyanogen 7 (and worked flawlessly) to cyanogen 9 and I can not build the platform. I am sure that I have all the includes and everything is fine with the .h files. In my opinion, it is just the linking of the libraries that possibly could cause the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that you need to add both the C includes and the libssl and libcrypto libraries in all 3 implementations of the sqlite located in the Android.mk file. That would be one implementation of the sqlite used by the android applications, and two sqlite implementations that are generated in the android platform.